# Format for C# commenting with NUnit and XML commenting

Tags: c#, xml, nunit

When writing C# code with NUnit and XML commenting is there a required, or preferred format for which comes first?

Would:

```
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace FooBar{

    /// <summary> 
    /// The <c>foo</c> class tests bar
    /// </summary>
    [TestFixture]
    public class Foo{
    }
}
```

be correct or would:

```
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace FooBar{

    [TestFixture]
    /// <summary> 
    /// The <c>foo</c> class tests bar
    /// </summary>
    public class Foo{
    }
}
```

be better?

Comment: i like the first one, attributes all together close to the code, code with code, comments before...

Comment: "Better" for whom, and with regards to which criteria?

Comment: ditto ... I prefer the first one. In fact the default "UnitTest1.cs" has commenting in the same way as the first example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't specific to NUnit - it's any attributes.

It's a matter of preference, but for me at least, the comments should come before the code - attributes count as code too.